# How to stop Windows store popping up while browsing in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, windows-store

I'm using Windows 10. Sometimes while I'm browsing the web in Google Chrome, the Windows Store app will spontaneously pop up on my desktop (outside Google Chrome). How can I stop this happening? It's annoying and intrusive.

[image]

Also, how is this possible? I checked `chrome://plugins` to see if a plugin was responsible, but none look relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Close all running instances of Chrome
2. Go to %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
3. There will be a file called Local State. Back it up to your desktop (just in case)
4. Open the file in the User Data folder in a text editor like Notepad.
5. Search for

   ```
    ms-windows-store
   ```
6. Change the value from false to true.
7. Save the file and then reopen Chrome and test out a webpage again. It should no longer open in Windows Store.

For more details about this method, [please see this link](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/03/25/block-firefox-chrome-windows-store/) for complete details.

Comment: @Ramhound Better now?

Comment: In the future I won't provide feedback to answers, like the original revision of this answer, you have enough answers under your belt you know what is expected from a quality answer.  I will provide feedback to other problems I see, as a curtsy, eventually I will won't though.  *I really hate having to repeating the same comments, to the same people multiple times, so I try to avoid that*